# htmlentities and htmlspecialchars stops text from displaying

Tags: php, sanitization, htmlspecialchars, strip-tags

I'm trying to display comments from a comment box form on my website. I originally displayed it by using:

```
<?php while($comment_text = mysqli_fetch_assoc($display_comments)) { ?>
<div class="comment" style="margin-bottom: 2em;">
    <div class="author">
      <b><?php echo htmlentities($comment_text["author"]); ?></b>
    <span class="datetime">
      <i><?php echo datetime_to_text($comment_text["created"]); ?></i>
    </span>
    </div>
  <div class="body">
        <?php echo strip_tags($comment_text["body"], '<strong><em><p>'); ?>
  </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Where I use "strip_tags" when the "body" text is displayed. However, I heard I should be using htmlentities or htmlspecialchars instead as it's safer, but whenever I try replacing "strip_tags" with one of them, the comment doesn't display. It just shows the comment's author and then nothing below it.

The form is working properly though, and I use "mysqli_real_escape_string" whenever I post to my database. I see the comments in the database, they just won't display when I use htmlentities or htmlspecialchars.

I'm pretty new at php, and I want to make sure my form is safe. Any help would be appreciated!

UPDATE: I've tried displaying different test comments. Nothing will show up when I use htmlspecialchars, even if it's something simple like "test"

Answer (score 1):

You will have to choose what you want to use: Either you allow some html tags and you cannot use `htmlspecialchars` or you use `htmlspecialchars` and do not allow any html.

Note that the first option has a risk of xss so you should not use it if the content is not trusted.

The problem is that when you use `htmlspecialchars`, all special characters get encoded, so instead of seeing some text bold, you will literally see the bold opening and closing tags surrounding the rendered text in the browser.

Comment: I understand it's best to use hmlspecialchars, I just don't understand why it's stopping my text from displaying at all. I tested it with really simple text, no html tags or anything, but still nothing displays

Comment: @coolpup Did you remove the second argument from the function?

Comment: Do you mean strip_tags? I removed that and replaced it with htmlspecialchars

Comment: @coolpup What does your actual code look like, could you post that under the original?